# Merge entries in two files by column [bash, sed, awk]

Tags: linux, bash, join, sed, awk

Есть два файла:

```
     $> cat 1.file    $> cat 2.file
```

```
     ABC-123;x;       ABC-123;y;100;
     XYZ-987;x;       XYZ-987;y;299;
     ABC-456;x;       XYZ-987;y;290;
                      ABC-456;y;400;
```

Я хотел бы получить итоговый файл в следующем виде:

```
    $> cat 3.file
```

```
    ABC-123;x;y;100;
    XYZ-987;x;y;299;
    XYZ-987;x;y;290;
    ABC-456;x;y;400;
```

1. Объединить данные по первому столбцу
2. Дублировать столько раз **XYZ-987** в `3.file`, сколько **XYZ-987** встречается в файле `2.file`

Comment: А это точно нужно делать на bash/sed/awk? Кажется проще взять какой-нибудь питон. Особенно если порядок строк не гарантирован

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/638536/136975 ?

Comment: Спасибо за идеи и предложения, но кажется, что действительно нужно пользоваться правильным инструментом. На данный момент, в распоряжении были те, что указаны в теме вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Пока что идеи таковы:

```
# Проходимся по всем ключам 1.file
# сохраняя первый столбец в f1, а остаток строки в row1
while IFS=';' read -u3 -r f1 row1; do
  # Если ключ из 1.file есть в 2.file
  if grep -icq ${f1} 2.file; then
    # То получаем строки из 2.file по $f1
    # через sed back-references \1 + \2
    # и компануем строку через \1$row1\2
    sed -rn "s/($f1;)(.*)/\1$row1\2/p" 2.file >> 3.file
  else
    # Иначе просто печатаем строку из 1.file как есть
    printf "%s;%s\n" "${f1}" "${row1}" >> 3.file
  fi
# Пишем в 3ий дескриптор столбцы разделяемые ;
# Где -f1 пойдет в $f1
# Где -f2- пойдет в $row1
done 3< <(cut -d';' -f1,2- 1.file)
```